# How can I make my bot to ask questions in sequence instead of random?

Tags: xml, aiml

Currently I am using AIML to make a basic bot Q&A function. Please view the following code:

```
<category>
<pattern>RANDOM PICKUP LINE</pattern>
<template>
    <random>
        <li>What is the first thing you have to do when consulting a patient?</li>
        <li>During the consultation, is there other person in the room, such as nurse?</li>
        <li>How can you determine what kind of illness does a patient have? </li>
        <li>When do you use the blood pressure monitor machine?</li>
    </random>
</template>
```

pattern − defines the pattern to match what a user may input to an Alicebot while

template − defines the response of an Alicebot to user's input.

However, We cannot predict what will a user input. How can I make the questions that asked by the bot in sequence instead of random.

What I mean is: The question will be asked sequentially. (instead of randomly)

```
User: Hi
Bot: What is the first thing you have to do when consulting a patient?
User: Normally, we will ask he/she what symptoms does he/she have.
Bot: During the consultation, is there other person in the room, such as nurse?
User: No.
Bot: How can you determine what kind of illness does a patient have?
User: Based on their symptoms, I can predict what kind of illness she/he is having.
Bot: When do you use the blood pressure monitor machine?
User: I will decide when should I use the machine after I used stethoscope to listen to patient's heart and lungs.
```

I have tried to remove the random tag, but it seems does not work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use that in aiml to do it

```
<aiml>
<category>
<pattern>hi</pattern>
<template>what car gives the best milage in 2018</template>
<category>

<category>
<that>what car gives the best milage in 2018</that>
<pattern>*</pattern>
<template>wrong.who is the richest carmaker?</template>
<category>

<category>
<that>what car gives the best milage in 2018</that>
<pattern>ford</pattern>
<template>you are corrrect.who is the richest carmaker?</template>
<category>

<category>
<that>what car gives the best milage in 2018</that>
<pattern>*</pattern>
<template>wrong.what was the last car company to go out of buisness?</template>
<category>

<category>
<that>wrong.what was the last car company to go out of buisness?</that>

<pattern>bill gord</pattern>
<template>you are corrrect.what was the last car company to go out of buisness?</template>
<category>

<category>
<that>you are corrrect.who is the richest carmaker?</that>

<pattern>bill gord</pattern>
<template>you are corrrect.what was the last car company to go out of buisness?</template>
<category>


</aiml>
the people are are fictional.
```

Answer (score 0):

so based on your question your are looking for a Q&A conversation by using the 
`template` for the respond and `that` for matching the previous question the bot asked you should be able to achieve what you are looking for

```
   <category>
      <pattern>Hi</pattern>
      <template>Do you like comedy movies</template>  
   </category>

   <category>
      <pattern>YES</pattern>
      <that>Do you like comedy movies</that>
      <template>Nice, I like comedy movies too.</template>
   </category>

   <category>
      <pattern>NO</pattern>
      <that>Do you like comedy movies</that>
      <template>Ok! But I like comedy movies.</template>
   </category> 

</aiml>
```

[source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/aiml/aiml_that_tag.htm)

Answer (score 0):

While the above examples will work, they are unnecessarily long winded. You can do this in your original category by amending it slightly:

```
<category>
<pattern>RANDOM PICKUP LINE</pattern>
<template>
<condition name="qnum">
    <li value="1">What is the first thing you have to do when consulting a patient?<think><set name="qnum">2</set></think></li>
    <li value="2">During the consultation, is there other person in the room, such as nurse?<think><set name="qnum">3</set></think></li>
    <li value="3">How can you determine what kind of illness does a patient have?<think><set name="qnum">4</set></think></li>
    <li value="4">When do you use the blood pressure monitor machine?<think><set name="qnum">1</set></think></li>
    <li><think><set name="qnum">1</set></think><srai>RANDOM PICKUP LINE</srai></li>
</condition>
</template>
```

We need to set a predicate to keep track of the question number, I called it "qnum". Now we use condition to find the value of "qnum" and display the appropriate response. We then increase "qnum" to display the next question when the category is next called. If we reach the end of the questions, reset "qnum" back to 1 so it starts again.

The bottom <li> is for the initial call. "qnum" hasn't been set and so we initialise it to 1 and call the category again to display the first question.