# AIML how to detect user repeat words

Tags: chatbot, aiml

In aiml how to detect user repeat sentence? Here's my code

<

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml>

<category><pattern>*</pattern>
    <template>
        <condition name="userlast">
            <li><value><star/></value>Why are you saying the same thing?</li>
            <li><value><star/></value>you are boring you just saying same thing all the time</li>
            <li>something from a random pool</li>
            <li>err</li>
            <li>mhm</li>
        </condition>
        <think><set name="userlast"><star></star></set></think>
    </template>
</category>

</aiml>
```

The output is

```
Human: ok
Robot: something from a random pool
Human: ok
Robot: why are you saying the same thing?
Human: ok
Robot: why are you saying the same thing?
```

My question is why my bot is not detecting word like

"you are boring you just saying same thing all the time"

Its just only replying why are you saying the same thing?

How to make it reply both sentence.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have asked your bot to say random responses, you've not included a random tag, so it will always say the first response. In fact, you need two random tags, one for when the user is repeating themselves and one for when they say something new. This category will do that:

```
<category>
    <pattern>*</pattern>
    <template>
        <condition name="userlast">
            <li><value><star/></value>
                <random>
                    <li>Why are you saying the same thing?</li>
                    <li>you are boring you just saying same thing all the time</li>
                </random>
            </li>
            <li>
                <random>
                    <li>something from a random pool</li>
                    <li>err</li>
                    <li>mhm</li>
                </random>
            </li>
        </condition>
        <think><set name="userlast"><star/></set></think>
    </template>
</category>
```

Bear in mind, that the random tag picks out a random response from your list and so you may find you get the same response two or three times in a row, especially if your list is just two entries.
Also as an AIML tip, you can use `<star/>` instead of `<star></star>`
This will save you a lot of typing :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer the above code just works fine but i have another doubt is how to do that in an order like this.

Comment: To ask things in a sequence instead of randomly, check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522485/how-can-i-make-my-bot-to-ask-questions-in-sequence-instead-of-random